# How to have Outlook emptying trash on quit without asking?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I leave my PC, I shut it down. But when it is the turn to Outlook to quit, he wants me to confirm that I want to delete what is in the trash folder.

[image]

So when I leave without waiting for this dialog to appear and not answering it, the PC get stuck on that dialog and then the shutdown is cancelled.

Is there a way to avoid this Dialog box, and still have my outlook trash folder cleaned on exit?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In **Outlook Options**, on the **Advanced** tab (same as where you marked to delete on closing) down at the bottom in the **Other** section is the option **Prompt for confirmation before permanently deleting items**.  Clear that checkbox, and it will stop prompting you before it empties your Deleted Items when you close your Outlook.

[image]

Comment: MS way to handle prefs and params : a bit everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

For example in MS Outlook 2007 go to Tools > Options > Other tab and check the empty deleted items on exit toggle.

Comment: I don't ask to "delete on exit", but "delete silently on exit". Do you feel the difference?